# FFmpeg: Could not get frame filename with strftime

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, video-capture, strftime

I want to have a timestamp in my JPEG files generated by FFmpeg.
I'm getting the above error message when executing FFmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -framerate 50 -i video="XI100DUSB-HDMI Video" -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_thumb%04d.jpg"
```

It also says:

av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

**Complete FFmpeg output:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-li
bopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=XI100DUSB-HDMI Video':
  Duration: N/A, start: 777552.702000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1920x1080, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
[swscaler @ 0000000001c8c940] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[mjpeg @ 0000000001c7ea60] removing common factors from framerate
Output #0, image2, to '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_thumb%04d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0000000001c7afe0] Could not get frame filename with strftime
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=7.9 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.02 bitrate=N/A speed=0.687x
video:101kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[dshow @ 0000000001c728a0] real-time buffer [XI100DUSB-HDMI Video] [video input] too full or near too full (136% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is being passed to strftime() for expansion, in which %d is reserved for date. You will have to add the sequence index numerals as a suffix using another tool like [Advanced Renamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/).

P.S. FFmpeg is dropping frames. Add `-rtbufsize 20M` before `-i video`

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya I didn't think about that.. But I need different filenames immediately, because it saves 50fps (otherwise overwriting). Are milliseconds still not supported? Or any other direct way to get some kind of index?

Comment: concerning the rtbufsize, in case of realtime encoding wouldn't it be better to use  -fflags nobuffer  at all (to minimize latency)?

Comment: I suggest to number the frames sequentially and maybe overlay the time on the video, or just below it.  Your feed is uncompressed FullHD frames. You'll drop (many) frames if there's no large buffer. There's no other stream here to sync with, so latency isn't an issue.

Comment: Ok thanks @Mulvya . I assume this means that there is no way for milliseconds.. too bad because this would solve everything. Actually it will be up to 4 streams so syncing might become an issue.. If more than 1 stream use nobuffer?

Comment: If you have enough RAM and CPU speed, just use a high rtbufsize for each input.